# Why does erlang shell receive exit message from spawned processes only once?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Here is code:

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> process_flag(trap_exit, true).
false
2> spawn_link(fun() -> exit(reason) end).
<0.63.0>
3> receive X -> X after 0 -> 'end' end.
{'EXIT',<0.63.0>,reason}
4> spawn_link(fun() -> exit(reason) end).
<0.66.0>
5> receive X -> X after 0 -> 'end' end.  
'end'
```

Why doesn't erlang shell receive exit message from second spawned process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the first `receive` succeeds, `X` gets bound to its returned value, which is `{'EXIT', <...>, reason}`. Since you use the same variable `X` in the second `receive`, `receive` waits for a message that exactly matches the old value of `X`, which won't match the second message because its PID is different than the first one.

To fix this, you can either use a different variable name:

```
1> process_flag(trap_exit, true).
false
2> spawn_link(fun() -> exit(reason) end).
<0.67.0>
3> receive X -> X after 0 -> 'end' end.
{'EXIT',<0.67.0>,reason}
4> X.
{'EXIT',<0.67.0>,reason}
5> spawn_link(fun() -> exit(reason) end).
<0.71.0>
6> receive X2 -> X2 after 0 -> 'end' end.
{'EXIT',<0.71.0>,reason}
```

or you can "forget" the value of `X` using `f/1` and then use `X` again (this will only work in the REPL):

```
7> spawn_link(fun() -> exit(reason) end).
<0.74.0>
8> f(X).
ok
9> receive X -> X after 0 -> 'end' end.
{'EXIT',<0.74.0>,reason}
```

Comment: Sure! A forgot about pattern matching, thanks for explanation.